# python で dict の特定の要素を関数適用でアップデートしたい

Tags: python

今、 dict `d` と、その特定の要素に対するアップデートとして適用したい関数 `f` があります。今、 dict のキー `k` に対して、以下の操作を行いたいです。

```py
d[k] = f(d[k])
```

これは、このように変数名が短い場合には、そこまで問題にはなりませんが、変数名が長くなってくると、これを行うのがつらくなってきます。

#### 質問

「dict の要素に対して関数 f を適用してアップデートを行う」を、綺麗に記述する方法などないでしょうか？

イメージとして、以下のような操作ができるといいなと思っています。

```py
d.replace(f, k)
```

Answer (score 2):

`dict` 型はミュータブルなので、関数の中で直接書き換えることが可能です。以下の例のように、 `f(d, k)` として関数適用を行うことが可能です。

```
def value_add_one(dic, key):
    dic[key] += 1


def main():
    some_dict = {
        "Alice": 10,
        "Bob": 20,
    }
    value_add_one(some_dict, "Bob")
    print(some_dict) # => {'Alice': 10, 'Bob': 21}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

ちなみに、イミュータブルな `dict` 型として、 `frozendict` 型もあります。